# Chrome keeps redirecting url

Tags: google-chrome, dns, browser, redirection

I was working on my wordpress website and I accidentally changed the internal URL of the site and accessed it once. Since then chrome **automatically** redirects to that URL even though I have reverted everything. Everything works fine in every other browser (even chrome incognito) but regular chrome doesn't want to cooperate.

Problem:

1. I type in mydomain.com
2. Google redirects me automatically to mydomain**s**.com
3. I go to mydomain.com/uri. Works fine.
4. I click on home from mydomain.com/uri which points to mydomain.com and chrome redirects to mydomain**s**.com

I have flushed my DNS and sockets pools in chrome, I have cleared the DNS on windows as well. Not quite sure what else I can do?

Comment: What happens when you try the domain in a private browsing window?  What about other browsers, and their 'private' modes?

Comment: "Everything works fine in every other browser (even chrome incognito) but regular chrome doesn't want to cooperate." It's in my original question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Browsers these days often times cache redirects.  You need to clear your file cache from before your mistaken change.  From [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7743980/498533)

> To force clear htaccess/redirect caches in Google Chrome:
>
> 1. Go to Settings > Advanced > Privacy > Clear Browsing Data
> 2. Select "Cached Images and Files"
> 3. Click Clear Browsing Data

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: There is an Easy Link to this chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

Comment: Worked. But it was hard for me to relate the DNS related config to categorization "Cached Images and Files", not something like "DNS", not "Cookies and other site data"